# How to install JSONModel from github manually

Tags: ios, xcode

I am following the instructions at https://github.com/jsonmodel/jsonmodel ... I am in Xcode 13.0

Manual

0. download the JSONModel repository
1. copy the JSONModel sub-folder into your Xcode project
2. link your app to SystemConfiguration.framework

I downloaded the JSONModel.

I copied the JSONModel sub-folder in my Xcode Project using File->Add files->Select the JSONModel sub-folder and click the add button. After i click the add button it shows up in my project tree the folder and i see an ? Unversioned next to it.

I added the SystemConfiguration.framework to my target using Build Phases->Link Binary With Libraries.

I then try to create a new JSONModel class using File->new->files->cocoa touch class but when i write at subclass of JSONModel does not show up! What am i missing?

Comment: Did you drag the built product of `JSONModel` to your app?

Comment: the build product? what do you mean? I added the sub-folder JSONModel as i mentioned above...

Comment: Make sure you have added files to your target and don't forget to use import. If you trying to use it in swift - see this [manual](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_objective-c_into_swift)

Comment: Why not use swift json decode and encode ? May be you are still using Objective-C ? In this case you have NSJSONSerialization

Comment: @PtitXav I am still using Objective C...

Comment: Not sure it should be a cocoa touch class.

Comment: Did you think to include JSONModel.h ?

Comment: I create a class and at the interface of .h of the class this line -> @interface JsonTest : JSONModel i get Class 'JsonTest' defined without specifying a base class so i guess it does not find it!